# How to use volume up and down controls in cocos2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am building a game where i want to use volume values on down
 and up.   Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by volume values ?

Comment: I want to get the value of volume up as positive  and  down as negative , to do some task on my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> value of volume up ?

As I understand you want to perform some action in your game when volume up/down button pressed.

When you press any button on Android `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` method called by your current Activity. Override these two methods and call your native method inside method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
          soundButtonPressed(false);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

     if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
          soundButtonPressed(true);
     return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

public static native void soundButtonPressed(boolean isUpVolumeKey);
```

And In native side make an implementation of your native method.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_soundButtonPressed(JNIEnv *env, jclass type,jboolean isUpVolumeKey) {

    // TODO

}
```